# Ceedling Cache disable

Tags: c, unit-testing, tdd

I'm trying to make two different Unit Test with different pre-processor macro definitions.

This could be achieved by defining different preprocessor directives like this:

```
:defines:
  # in order to add common defines:
  #  1) remove the trailing [] from the :common: section
  #  2) add entries to the :common: section (e.g. :test: has TEST defined)
  :commmon: &common_defines
    - UNITY_INT_WIDTH=16
    - CMOCK_MEM_INDEX_TYPE=uint16_t
    - CMOCK_MEM_ALIGN=1
    - CMOCK_MEM_SIZE=4096
  :test:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST
  :test_preprocess:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST
  :test_option0:
    - *common_defines
    # Option 0 config.
    - CONFIG_OPTION_STUFF=OPTION0
  :test_option1:
    - *common_defines
    # Option 1 config.
    - CONFIG_OPTION_STUFF=OPTION1
```

The cached header file where the options are being processed is only available with the option0, as was the first test processed.

Is there a way to disable caching for specific tests or the whole project?

**EDITED**:

I found a way to hack the Ceedling to my needs. It is available in my [github repo](https://github.com/methril/Ceedling/tree/preprocessing). Any comment or improvement is very welcome.

Comment: What do you mean with "cached header files"?

Comment: The pre-processed header files are cached on build/ directory, with the first option being parsed. So you could not check different pre-processor options for diferent tests.

Comment: Seems no-one understands your question. Stil don't understand "cached". In C++ you have "pre-compiled header files". in C, the header files are just read from the directory as indicated in the paths. There is no caching at all.

Comment: May have something to do with the tools you are using. Then add the tags for those tools to your question.

Comment: Ok @PaulOgilvie, let me explain. The pre-processed files for all tests are in the same folder, so when you try to make two tests with different pre-processor definitions, the second one fails, as it is not pre-processed again.

Comment: Oh dear...THERE ARE NO PRE-PROCESSED FILES IN C!!!! There are header files. And upon _compilation/pre-processing_ you can define a pre-processor symbol. So you will probably have to recompile with the other symbol defined and then run the other test. You can do that in a makefile or provide the symbol on the command line to the compiler, e.g. `-DMyDefine2`. And you can tweak the makefile to use different directories for the executable depending on the make target.

Comment: There is a pre-process step into the C compiler, that could be decoupled from the compilation.
The ceedling folder structure has ./build/test/preprocess folder, as well as ./build/test/cache folder.
I don't know exactly the ceedling internals to know at which step each file is generated, but the files are pre-processed and stored on a folder.

Comment: Change your tools or read their documentation. This is highly non-standard and is not part of the C language.

Comment: Do you know the Ceedling tool? This is not a C tool, is a ruby wrapper that help to define and process UnitTests. For doing so, it does different C toolchain steps: Pre-processing, compiler dependencies, and code tunning.
Is a helpful tool for the UnitTest purpouses. You shuld give a try.

Comment: As said before, why don't you tag your question for your Ceeding tool?

Comment: Because there is no ceedling tag, and I have no points to create a new tag.